# Submenu/Drop-down items taking up space among main navbar items - why?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar, submenu

I'm using a template, [HTML5UP - Miniport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZdX3.jpg), for my web design class - I'm just beginning to learn to code. In order to meet the specification for my class I needed to add submenus/drop-down navbar. This works fine in desktop mode, but when I decrease the size of the windows, I get some problems. The submenus stay inside the fixed navbar, pushing their way between other menus items. Here's a link to what it currently looks like:

https://jsfiddle.net/OrangeJones/9u0seLxu/

The CSS is in the fiddle link, but here's my HTML.

```
            <div class="nav">
              <ul class="container">
                <li><a class="jumper home" href="#top">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="jumper about" href="#about">About</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="Name's Resume 2015.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="jumper portfolio" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="jumper blog" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="datajournalism.html">Best of the Twin Cities</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="jumper contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

How can I get it to where the submenus drop down when hovered over or clicked on in small screens instead of taking up main navbar space.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for the submenu to show and hide is inside the media query and so the dropdown elements were showing when on a screen that was smaller instead of being hidden, you also had the deceleration of the background for the submenu elements in the media query.

```
.nav li ul 
{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
}

.nav li:hover ul
{
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul li 
{
  display: block;
  background-color: #282828;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9u0seLxu/2/)